# Echo pin reads low all the time

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to code distance sensor HC-SR04 with my Raspberry Pi. Following code, reads low all the time.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using RaspberryPiDotNet;

namespace Pi_Projects
{
  class Program
  {
    static GPIOMem echo = new GPIOMem(GPIOPins.V2_GPIO_02, GPIODirection.In);
    static GPIOMem trigger = new GPIOMem(GPIOPins.V2_GPIO_03, GPIODirection.Out);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        trigger.Write(PinState.High);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        trigger.Write(PinState.Low);

        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(echo.Read());
        }

    }
  }
}
```

To make sure connections and code are working, I've touched ECHO pin with 3.3V power, then console reads High. Plugged in LED to ECHO pin and it quickly blinks, so technically console should read High. Also, have python code to test sensor. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that this question belongs on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/